# iText java v7.1.8 not supporting RSASSA-PSS Encryption Algorithm? For signature verification?

Tags: java, algorithm, itext, digital-signature

I'm trying to validate a PDF which is signed with RSASSA-PSS algorithm. 
I get this error which let me think the lack of support in iText (EncryptionAlgorithms).

Error:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA256with1.2.840.113549.1.1.10 Signature not available
```

Code:

```
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.signatures.EncryptionAlgorithms;
import com.itextpdf.signatures.PdfPKCS7;
import com.itextpdf.signatures.SignatureUtil;

public void verifySignature(byte[] pdf, List<PublicKey> storedPublicKeys) throws PdfSignatureVerificationException {
        try (final PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(pdf))) {
            PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);
            SignatureUtil signatureUtil = new SignatureUtil(doc);
            List<String> names = signatureUtil.getSignatureNames();
            if (names == null || names.isEmpty()) {
                throw new PdfSignatureVerificationException("Pdf is not signed");
            }
            verifySignatures(signatureUtil, names, storedPublicKeys);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new PdfSignatureVerificationException("Cannot parse PDF data into pdf file.", e);
        }
    }

private void verifySignatures(SignatureUtil signUtil, List<String> names, List<PublicKey> storedPublicKeys) throws PdfSignatureVerificationException {

        for (String name : names) {
            PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = signUtil.readSignatureData(name);

            try {
                if (!pkcs7.verifySignatureIntegrityAndAuthenticity()) {
                    throw new PdfSignatureVerificationException("Signature not valid");
                }
            } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
                throw new PdfSignatureVerificationException("Signature not valid", e);
            }    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Correct. And unfortunately support for RSASSA-PSS is not as easy to patch in as many other algorithms are because it is one of the few common algorithm requiring use of the paramSpec.

Comment: Hi! I noticed that you also contacted iText Software about this, your question is registered in our Jira as SUP-4734. One of our developers will get back to you as soon as possible. To avoid duplication, we'll keep the communication in Jira. However, once the issue is solved to your satisfaction, you are very welcome to report back here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi Amedee Yes I reportet to Jira on iText to..... I found a solution witch i postet in the Jira.... Its a ugli hack but for now It did the job.

Comment: Hi, any chance to add the solution here?

Comment: you can now use iText 8 for this